# I can't curl nginx which I deployed on k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, service

my deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels: 
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

my service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp4l8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXIUM.png)

and then I `curl 10.104.239.140`, but get an error `curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.104.239.140:80; Connection timed out`

Who can tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO. That service you've deployed is of type `ClusterIP` which means it can only be accessed from within the cluster. In your case, it seems you're trying to access it from outside the cluster and thus the `connection timed out`.

What you can do is, deploy a service of type `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` to access it from outside the cluster. You can read more about different service types [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

You're service would end up something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort      ## or LoadBalancer(supported by Cloud providers like AWS)    
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    # Optional field
    # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
    nodePort: 30001
```

Comment: oh,thanks for your answer,i have already solve this problem,by adding `type:NodePort`，but it only can access this server outside the cluster,and can't access this server inside.

Comment: From inside the cluster, you can continue to use the Cluster-IP which you tried to do earlier.

Comment: If this solved your problem, could you please mark it as answer for others to know & follow it in future.

Comment: if i want to access this service both inside and outside on the cluster at the same time,how can i do?don't modify the yml.

Comment: you can access it by `<nope-ip>:<nodeport>` . It works from both inside & outside the cluster.